# Getting "module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'" when using imaplib with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, imaplib

I am using imaplib to read some emails. This code works without error within Pycharm. I have used cx_Freeze to make this program an executable, and now I get an error that traces back to cx_Freeze's startup.py. I have made an executable before, not with imaplib, and this kind of problem didn't happen.

There are other posts online about a "module imaplib has no attribute IMAP4_SSL", but these do not solve the problem and may have different causes than mine. Other causes for that statement involve virtual environments or things different than my situation.

The full error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run module.run() 
 File "C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscrips\Console.py", line 26, in run exec(code, m.__dict__)
 File "Main.py", line 18, in <module>
 File 'C:Users\Todd\Desktop\ForStemotics\EmailGetter.py", line 43, in GetEmails
  mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
AttributeError: module 'imaplib' has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'
```

**EDIT in setup.py from comments:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name = 'SARS', 
      version='0.1', 
      description = 'email automator', 
      executables = [Executable("Main.py")])
```

Comment: Can you also share your setup.py? (or whatever you used to bundle it as an executable)

Comment: Ok, here is my setup.py: line 1: from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable, next line: setup(name = 'SARS', version='0.1', description = 'email automator', executables = [Executable("Main.py")]), and that's it.

Comment: Please don't put codes in comments. You can click on the **[edit]** link to update your post (ex. to put additional info). I've edited in your setup.py for you this time.

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who contributed and viewed. I have solved the problem. After some experimenting I traced the problem to the ssl module. I couldn't find a way around this but I found another fix. I upgraded from python 3.7.1 to the latest version 3.7.3 and the problem stopped. I don't know why this is, but if anyone else was experiencing mine or a similar problem I would recommend this as something to try.